# Getting mp3 from Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, encoding, mp3, azure-media-services

I'm using Azure Media Services and I need to encode input audio files to mp3 output files. I've used Standart Encoder for encoding video files, but it seems Standart Encoder can't produce mp3 (I understand that it can encode audio with AAC and produce mp4 file with the audio but unfortunately I need exactly mp3).
So I'm trying to use Media Encoder Premium Workflow. In the documentation, I see that I need to use Workflow Designer tool but can't understand where I can get it. Could you please point me out where I can find it? 
 Or maybe you can suggest other solution for getting mp3 after processing audio using Azure Media Services?

Comment: An blob triggered Azure Function that invokes ffmpeg.exe is probably a much more straight forward solution. There's a five minute execution timeout on Consumption plans, just be aware of that. Since it's audio, it shouldn't be a problem unless each file is one hour long.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll definitely consider this solution. But the files might be more than an hour long. And as we already have a system that uses AMS we would like to keep it consistent and proceed using AMS where it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have considered Azure Functions. Since that does not appear to address your needs, please contact us via mepd@microsoft.com

We'll provide you the instructions on how to download the Workflow Designer, and use it.